# trying to get swagger to run with play framework v2.4

Tags: swagger, playframework-2.3, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to get swagger/swagger-ui to work with play framework v2.4 (java app).  I did the following:

a) copied the swagger-ui dist directory to the /public/ directory, 
b) copied the index.html as swagger.scala.html to the app/views directory (along with adding the play import statement, modified references to static assets as well as JS function), 
c) made changes to my routes file (copied below) and 
d) added a scala controller (for swagger).

Any ideas if I am missing any steps?

I am getting the error copied below when I try to compile the app (I was under the impression that the ApiHelpController was part of the play-swagger module and I did not need to copy it. Please share if I did not follow the steps correctly.

**Error:**

```
[error] /home/user/testapp/conf/routes:165: object ApiHelpController is not a member of package controllers
[error] Note: class ApiHelpController exists, but it has no companion object.
[error] GET         /api-docs.json               controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
[error] /home/user/testapp/conf/routes:167: object ApiHelpController is not a member of package controllers
[error] Note: class ApiHelpController exists, but it has no companion object.
[error] GET         /api-docs.json/hello         controllers.ApiHelpController.getResource(path = "/accesses")
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

**routes file**

```
GET         /swagger                     @controllers.Application.swagger
GET         /api-docs.json               @controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources

GET         /api-docs.json/accesses         @controllers.ApiHelpController.getResource(path = "/accesses")
```

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.1",
  "org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "2.1.8-M1"
)
```

**application.conf**

## Swagger

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule"

api.version="1.0"
swagger.api.basepath="http://localhost:9000"
```

**controller**

```
package controllers


import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

    def swagger = Action {
      request =>
        Ok(views.html.swagger())
    }

  }
```

**Update**
After realizing that in play v2.4, I can use the dependency injected router with an "@" before the controller in the routes file (but then I have to use a scala class and not an object), I was able to move past the previous issue.  I am getting the following error now:

```
[error] /home/user/testapp/app/controllers/TestController.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
[error] @Api(value = "/accesses", description = "Test for Accesses")
[error]  ^
```

**Another Update**
The second issue was caused by missing import statements in the controller.

Adding the following in the controller solved it:

```
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
```

Comment: I was able to get the setup working once I went past the initial issues mentioned in the post

Comment: What is the swagger-ui you used in this case? Can you send the link/github-link ?

Comment: In my case, i used the same thing, but in swagger "try it out" is not working. Can someone guide me here on urgent basis?